# Java Invoke Collection of Tasks (as with invokeAll)

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, task, executorservice

I am searching for a way to do with `javafx.concurrent.Task`, what can be done with `java.util.concurrent.Callable` and `ExecutorService.invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>)` This method can't be used with Tasks as they are runnables and not callables.

Casting the type of my Tasks to Callable with `Executors.callable(Runnable task)` is not working because the returned `Callable` will always return null and I need the value returned from `Task.call()`.

I understand a `Task` is not designed to be used in `Collections`. However I need a `Task` in my JavaFX application and bumped into this problems by writing tests.

Are there any ideas how to circumvent this other than simply making my `Task` implement `Callable`? Which I do not want to do, as I would change my code to fit my tests then.

Comment: You're talking about `Runnable` at one point and `Callable` at another. Rewrite your question so it's a lot more clear than what it is currently. Also, explain what's wrong with making your Task implement `Callable`.

Comment: I did, do you understand the matter better?

Comment: Yes, and from here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166449 we can see that implementing `Callable` would not be a very good idea. I edited your question a bit to highlight the difference.

Comment: Can't you just wrap all the tasks in a `Callable`, i.e. something like `exec.invokeAll(tasks.stream().map(t -> () -> {t.run(); return t.getValue();}).collect(toList()));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap each task in a callable. Essentially for each `Task<T> task`, you need a `Callable<T>` as follows:

```
Callable<T> callable = () -> {
    task.run();
    return task.getValue();
};
```

So, for example, you can define a `Function<Task<T>, Callable<T>>` that performs this mapping

```
Function<Task<T>, Callable<T>> taskWrapper = task -> () -> {
    task.run();
    return task.getValue();
};
```

and then given an `ExecutorService exec` and `Collection<Task<T>> tasks` you can do

```
List<Future<T>> results = exec.invokeAll(tasks.stream()
    .map(taskWrapper)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class InvokeAllTasks extends Application {

    private Random rng = new Random();
    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    private Function<Task<Integer>, Callable<Integer>> taskWrapper = task -> () -> {
        task.run();
        return task.getValue();
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button runAll = new Button("Run all tasks");
        Label status = new Label();

        runAll.setOnAction(e -> {
            List<Task<Integer>> tasks = createTasks();


            Task<List<Future<Integer>>> runAllTask = new Task<List<Future<Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<Future<Integer>> call() throws Exception {
                    return exec.invokeAll(tasks.stream().map(taskWrapper).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
            };
            status.setText("Running...");
            runAllTask.setOnSucceeded(evt -> status.setText("All Done"));
            new Thread(runAllTask).start();


        });

        VBox root = new VBox(5, runAll, status);
        root.setMinHeight(120);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    private List<Task<Integer>> createTasks() {
        List<Task<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 8 ; i++) {
            String name = "Task "+i;
            Task<Integer> t = new Task<Integer>() {
                @Override
                protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(name+" running");
                    Thread.sleep(rng.nextInt(1000)+500);
                    int result = rng.nextInt(500);
                    System.out.println(name+" computed "+result);
                    return result;
                }
            };
            tasks.add(t);
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I read this again after some time as it helped me a lot. There is one thing I don't understand though.
Why is the Label status set "All Done", precisely when alle values are computed.

Comment: @J.Ober [`ExecutorService.invokeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) blocks until all the callables passed to it are complete, so `runAllTask` enters the `SUCCEEDED` state exactly when all the individual tasks are complete.